# Принцип работы многопользовательского чата C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно сделать многопользовательский чат на C# (один сервер, много клиентов), объясните принцип, какие классы использовать, как запоминать пользователей и как отправлять всем сообщения (если один клиент захочет отослать другому клиенту сообщение)

СПАСИБО!

ЗЫ. пробовал с помощью tcpclient и TcpListener, но тут сервер может только принимать сообщения от пользователей, а как отправлять обратно или всем - не знаю

2Воздух
я не просил решить все за меня, мне нужно узнать как внутри это работает и с помощью чего это реализовать самому.
у меня 2 проекта: сервер и клиент, сервер (Tcplistener) принимает запросы от клиентов (Tcpclient), будь то просто подключение или обычные сообщения, клиентов может быть несколько: если один клиент написал сообщение, то видит его только сервер, как сделать чтобы видели все клиенты или какой нибудь конкретный

2fori1ton Спасибо

Comment: @Павел Петров, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Нужно подумать, какие сущности будут участвовать в процессе и начать писать код, который реализует их функциональность. Почему-то многие думают, что для каждой задачи есть список классов, который известен только гуру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Несложный пример TCP-сервера](http://round-angle-net.blogspot.com/2010/09/tcpip-c.html)
2. [Подробная документация на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335942.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй воспользоваться [этим](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44357/Global-Text-Chat-Room-Application-using-C-NET-Remo) проектом в качестве точки отсчета.